# How can I add a component inside another component without template in Tapestry?

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a component without template, how can I add another component (render) inside it?

```
public class Component1 {

    void beginRender(MarkupWriter writer) {
        // How can I render for example a tapestry's textfield component inside this component without have a template?
    }

}
```

Note: Component1 has no template (tml file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, You can not add a component inside another component without a template, you need a template for add a component, this is because tapestry has a static structure.